# How to reuse a global javascript file within a vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Lang object created from lang.min.js from:

https://github.com/rmariuzzo/Lang.js

in my Laravel app I have the following in `app.js`:

```
import SearchToggle from './components/toggle.vue'
import Lang from './lang.min.js'
...
Vue.component('toggle', Toggle);
...
var lang = new Lang();
lang.setMessages(require('./messages.js'));
console.log(lang.getLocale());
console.log(lang.get('main.specialties'));
...
```

the lang objects has no errors and manage to output the get as intended.

Now I have a vue component in the following directory which was imported as shown above:
`ressource/assets/js/components/toggle.vue`

in the script section:

```
<script>
export default{
        data(){
            return {
                text_holder: lang.get('main.specialties'),

            }
        },
  ...
}
```

However this doesn't work. It complains that the lang is undefined.
I think I'm missing the gap (concept) of javascript scope. I thought that if everything is in the app.js and got imported then the var lang would have been int he global scope and I would be allowed to use it anywhere across the the import (similar to how vendor is from php)
I guess not.

Now what do I do?
pull in an import on each vue component (but then I have to ensure the path going backward is correct and also multi loading the same object / message.js will bloat the javascript.

Would appreciate the JS help.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

Comment: @ceejayoz but the object from the lang.min.js is not a state - its a reference object that gets its message loaded into a json file format. so its like carrying around a configured static array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your `lang.js`, and export the lang instance

```
var lang = new Lang();
lang.setMessages(require('./messages.js'));
...
export default lang;
```

then you can import and use that instance in your components

```
import lang from 'path/to/lang'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      text_holder: lang.get('main.specialties'),
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

another way is to write [plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html), you can inject `lang` to Vue, so you are able to access `lang` in your components.

Comment: wouldn't importing it in each components bloat out the vue?

Comment: No, the `import` in javascript will only import the module once

Comment: so you saying that if I have 16 components and all of them `import` the same file javascript is actually importing once?

Comment: Yes, you can try it.

Comment: I tried your solution the export works but I get the following when using within a component:
`[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "lang.get('main.specialties')": TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined (found in component: <toggle>)`

Comment: Make sure you export and import correctly, it should work. Or I have to see the full repository to know why.